# No lighting in VTK

Tags: python, vtk

I'd like to just display the polygons in their specified colour with no shading, is this possible? I've tried setting each of ambient, specular, diffuse etc. to 1 and the others to 0 with no luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To disable shading you really have to set lightning off.

To do so specify `actor.GetProperty().LightingOff()` on the respective vtkActor.
See e.g. http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkProperty.html

Based on the [vtk Pyramid](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/GeometricObjects/Display/Pyramid) the effect can be seen in the following example

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with vtkRotationalExtrusionFilter in Activiz's C# wrapper.